# Upgrading Symfony 2.2 to 2.3 causes silent 500 errors

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2, symfony-2.3

I just upgraded my Symfony 2.2 installation to Symfony 2.3. I was abe to get "composer update" to run with no errors, but this has caused every route in my application to return a blank page. If I check the network tab on my JavaScript console, I see that a 500 Internal Server Error is being thrown, but have no insight as to what might be causing it. Any ideas? Here's my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "*",
    "sandeepshetty/shopify_api": "dev-master@dev"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you set debug true in your web/app.php, to display errors ? ($kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect your logifles in order to find the exception... `app/logs/dev.log` or `app/logs/prod.log` depending on which environment you are trying to access.

And clear your cache :-)

```
app/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable it manually in 2.3.

Debug::enable();

See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.3/UPGRADE-2.3.md

Answer (score 1):

Update those lines from your composer.json thouse versions are not supported by symfony >= 2.3

Before

```
"jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*",
"jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
```

After

```
"jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
"jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
```

Regards.